# `npx mrm@2 lint-staged` throw err that `.git` can't be found husky custom directrory

Tags: prettier, pre-commit, husky

```
xxx-MacBook-Pro:client xxx$ npx mrm@2 lint-staged 
npx: installed 239 in 8.29s
Running lint-staged...
/Users/xxx/.npm/_npx/34378/lib/node_modules/mrm/bin/mrm.js:56
        throw err;
        ^

Error: .git can't be found (see https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=custom-directory)
    at Object.install (/Users/xxx/.npm/_npx/34378/lib/node_modules/mrm/node_modules/husky/lib/index.js:20:15)
    at task (/Users/xxx/.npm/_npx/34378/lib/node_modules/mrm/node_modules/mrm-task-lint-staged/index.js:214:8)
    at /Users/xxx/.npm/_npx/34378/lib/node_modules/mrm/src/index.js:170:20
```

I got the error while trying to install `Pre-commit Hook` using `lint-staged`

#### Environment

- npm : 6.14.17
- node: 14.19.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed:

- npx mrm@2 lint-staged

  Failed
- Fix the npm prepare script
  `"prepare": "cd .. && husky install client/.husky"`
- run `npm i` then
- Added `pre-commit` manually

  ```
   #!/bin/sh  

   "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

   cd client && npx lint-staged
  ```
- run `npm i` again

Reason: [package.json file and .git directory are not at the same level.](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=custom-directory)

My code structure:

> client
> server
> .gitignore

Comment: That does the trick `package.json file and .git directory are not at the same level.`